# Limits and Continuity of a Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $f(z)= (\frac{(Im(z))^3}{|z|^2})  \;\;\;\;\;\ z\neq0\\
                  \qquad \;\;\;\;\;\;0\qquad \quad  z=0\\$

$\quad$ is continuous for all $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$.

I have done this by checking that the limit is the same over two paths, real and imaginary. I think that both paths equal 0. Is this enough to confirm continuity?

I have done the same for

Prove that $f(z)= \frac{\bar{z}}{z} \qquad z\neq0 \\
\qquad \; \; 0 \qquad z=0 \\$

is not continuous at $z_0=0$, but continuous for all other $z_0$,

and have gotten that the real and imaginary paths have different limits when tending to $0$ but i don't know how to show that it is continuous for all other $z_0$.

Comment: No, you should you consider all possible paths towards zero, not just that coming through the $x$ or $y$ axis, in the first question. Remember the sequential definition of continuity, and note that nothing special is said about the sequence, it could approach the point through any direction it likes.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, we have $|f(z)|=\dfrac{\left|\text{Im}(z)\right|^{3}}{|z|^{2}}\leq\dfrac{|z|^{3}}{|z|^{2}}=|z|$ for $z\ne 0$. Of course this inequality also satisfies for $z=0$. Anyway we have $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}|f(z)|=0$ by Squeeze Theorem, then $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f(z)=f(0)$.

Considering only two paths to prove existence is not conclusive.